# Why is AutoScaleMode property not included in WPF?

Tags: wpf, autoscaling

I have run into a situation where although MinWidth and MinHeight properties have same values at Windows Resolution (on Windows 7), but still my application is not displayed completely on the screen (some of the top part and some of the area on the right is cut). For example:

```
MinWidth="1280" MinHeight="960"
```

And the Windows resolution is set to 1280x960. Still application is not completely displayed. However, if I change the resolution DPI to smaller (96dpi), application is displayed properly. How can I set AutoScaleMode to dpi in WPF application.

Even after @Abe Heidebrecht answer, I see no improvement in result. For example here is what my user interface looks like when I maximize the application: (please note that I have a seconds monitor, and black area is on second monitor)

[image]

Comment: Show your XAML. Most probably you created your UI using the Visual Studio designer, as opposed to doing it the right way (which is typing the XAML yourself by hand). Therefore your UI is full of fixed sizes and positions. And btw, WPF is resolution independent by default and natively, it does not need `AutoScale` or any other dinosaur winforms' horrible hacks.

Comment: Winforms == dinosaur. Never a truer word spoken. +1 for the comment on the visual studio designer. Why did MS do this to us :(

Answer (score 4):

WPF uses device independent pixels. In WPF, 1 pixel is supposed to be 1/96th of an inch (because 96DPI was mot common when WPF was developed). Therefore, if your monitor has a higher DPI, WPF will actually report that you have more pixels than 1280x960. [Here is a blog post that I thought explained things well](http://www.wpflearningexperience.com/?p=41).

I would use the [`SystemParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) class to get what you're after:

```
Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidthKey}}"
Height="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeightKey}}"
```